# Interactive Grails and Git Bash

Tags: bash, git, grails

Is anyone using Grails with Git Bash successfully on Windows? I have installed Grails (3 different versions) via SDKMAN using Git Bash. I cannot get an interactive Grails terminal to work, though. I call 'grails', get the Grails prompt, but then when I try a command like 'clean', say, it never completes, it just hangs there. What is more, Ctrl-C doesn't abort the command either, I have to close the console window.

Comment: Apologies.  I deleted "Is anyone using Grails with Git Bash successfully on Windows? " from the question as I didn't think it added anything and then it occurred to me that might actually be the intended question.  I reverted that change to put that text back.  The answer is "yes".

Answer (score 1):

I have found something which appears to work for this. If I call 'winpty bash' first, then the command becomes properly interactive and no longer hangs.